# Python - как переписать генератор списка без zip?

Tags: python, list

Всем привет. Есть два списка и есть скрипт, который эти списки сравнивает

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60,40,45]
x=[10,50,5,100,15,60]
print([i > j for i, j in zip(a[-len(x):], x)])
```

Мне нужно переписать его в "привычный формат", но полученный код результат дает неверный. Как мне быть?

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60,40,45]
x=[10,50,5,100,15,60]

for i in range (a[-len(x)]):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if i>j:
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')
```

Comment: Вы в `range` отдаете какой-то элемент из списка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60,40,45]
x=[10,50,5,100,15,60]

for i in range(min(len(a), len(x))):
  print(a[i] > x[i])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `len(a) if len(a) <= len(x) else len(x)` -> `min(len(a),len(x))`

Comment: о спасибо ща поправлю